# Sorting Multidimensional Associative Array with 2 custom criteria: (Meals by Day of Week and Meal Time)

Tags: php, sorting, multidimensional-array

I have a multidimensional array which needs to be sorted by two custom criteria in order:

1. Day of Week
2. Meal of Day (breakfast/lunch/dinner)

Documentation of `array_multisort()` and `uksort()` have gotten me half way there each, but I am unable to put it all together meaningfully. Thank you for your time

```
Array
(
    [name] => hashbrowns
    [day] => monday
    [mealTime] => breakfast
)
Array
(
    [name] => Steak
    [day] => monday
    [mealTime] => dinner
)
Array
(
    [name] => Avacados
    [day] => tuesday
    [mealTime] => dinner
)
Array
(
    [name] => Peaches
    [day] => tuesday
    [mealTime] => lunch
)
Array
(
    [name] => Sammich
    [day] => monday
    [mealTime] => lunch
)
Array
(
    [name] => Kale & Sadness
    [day] => tuesday
    [mealTime] => breakfast
)
```

Desired output example:

```
Array
(
    [name] => hashbrowns
    [day] => monday
    [mealTime] => breakfast
)
Array
(
    [name] => Sammich
    [day] => monday
    [mealTime] => lunch
)
Array
(
    [name] => Steak
    [day] => monday
    [mealTime] => dinner
)
Array
(
    [name] => Kale & Sadness
    [day] => tuesday
    [mealTime] => breakfast
)
Array
(
    [name] => Peaches
    [day] => tuesday
    [mealTime] => lunch
)
Array
(
    [name] => Avacados
    [day] => tuesday
    [mealTime] => dinner
)
```

Comment: Can you share the results you're looking for and what you've tried to get there?

Comment: Have added a desired output example

Comment: What code have you written and tried? It's good you started with the documentation, please show us what you've tried so far.

Answer (score 0):

try this solution. Surely it can be done with php functions but what happened to you seems to work.

```
$data = array(
array("name" => "Otra cosa","day" => "thursday","mealTime" => "dinner"),
array("name" => "hashbrowns","day" => "monday","mealTime" => "breakfast"),
array("name" => "Steak","day" => "monday","mealTime" => "dinner"),
array("name" => "Avacados","day" => "tuesday","mealTime" => "dinner"),
array("name" => "Cuchu","day" => "monday","mealTime" => "breakfast"),
array("name" => "Avacados 2","day" => "monday","mealTime" => "lunch"));



$day = array("monday" => 0, "tuesday" => 1, "wednesday" => 2, "thursday" => 3, "friday" => 4, "saturday" => 5, "sunday" => 6);
$mealTime = array("breakfast" =>0, "lunch" =>1, "dinner" => 2);


$result = array();

foreach($data as $values) {
    $d = $day[$values["day"]];
    $mt = $mealTime[$values["mealTime"]];
    if(!isset($result[$d])) {
        $result[$d] = array();
    }
    if(!isset($result[$d][$mt])) {
        $result[$d][$mt] = array();
    }

    $result[$d][$mt][] = $values;
    ksort($result[$d]);

}
ksort($result);
$_result = array();

foreach($result as $r) {
    foreach($r as $_r) {
        foreach($_r as $__r) {
            $_result[] = $__r;
        }
    }
}

return $_result;

//print_r("<pre>");
//print_r($_result);
//print_r("</pre>");
```

Comment: Added a substantial amount of data including duplicates, items on same day/meal.  Can confirm this is a nice solution.  Thinking I should wait to accept as solution if only to see if there's something using PHP native sort functions/further discussion.  Thank you very much.

Comment: Hello, I was looking native functions well above, you can expect but for now already have a solution :)

Answer (score 0):

Very interesting question!

I have tried to abstract from it to create a generic function to order a multidimensional array by given array of criteria.

The result is the function below, which has as first parameter a multidimensional array like that provided in the question, and as second parameter a multidimensional array of associative arrays, each with the key to be sorted as key (i.e. 'day') and the desired sorted values as values (i.e. 'monday','tuesday',...). You can pass one, two or more criteria. If a row don't match the criteria, is appended at the end of resulting array; same if a row has the key criteria but their value is not in the criteria values (i.e. has the key='day' with value='everyday').

So, in your case, you have to do in this way:

```
$menu = //Your array//
$criteria = array
(
    'day' => explode( ',', 'monday,tuesday,wednesday,thursday,friday,saturday,sunday' ), 
    'mealTime' => explode( ',', 'breakfast,lunch,dinner' )
);

$result = sortArrayByCriteria( $menu, $criteria );
```

You can see the result in this <kbd>**[eval.in demo](https://eval.in/510051)**</kbd> (I have added to your array a fake item to see the behavior when there is a non-matching criteria).

#### The function:

```
/*  Sort a multidimensional array by an array of criteria which keys are 
 *  the key to sort and values are the sort criteria
 *  Unmatched values are appended at the end of array.
 *
 *  @param  array  $array     array to be sorted
 *  @param  array  $criteria  array of criteria
 *
 *  @return array  sorted array
 */
function sortArrayByCriteria( $array, $criteria ) 
{
    # Extract current (last) criteria and reduce criteria array:
    $sortValues = end( $criteria );
    $sortKey    = key( $criteria );
    array_pop( $criteria );

    $sorted = $unsorted = array();
    foreach( $sortValues as $compare )
    {
        $key = 0;
        # Check each array:
        while( $key < count( $array ) )
        {
            # If array row doesn't have key to sort, add-it to unsorted array:
            if( !isset($array[$key][$sortKey]) )
            { $unsorted[] = reset( array_splice( $array, $key, 1 ) ); }
            else
            {
                # If value==current comparisation value, add-it to sorted:
                if( $array[$key][$sortKey] == $compare ) 
                { $sorted[] = reset( array_splice( $array, $key, 1 ) ); }
                # If value doesn't is in the comparisation values, add-it to unsorted:
                elseif( !in_array( $array[$key][$sortKey], $sortValues ) )
                { $unsorted[] = reset( array_splice( $array, $key, 1 ) ); }
                # Otherwise increment index pointer:
                else $key++;
            }
        }
    }
    # Merge sorted and unsorted values in one array:
    $retval = array_merge( $sorted, $unsorted );
    # If there are others criteria, performs a self-call:
    if( count( $criteria ) ) $retval = sortArrayByCriteria( $retval, $criteria );

    return $retval;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider simply adding `mealnumber` and `daynumber` to main array, sort by those numeric fields using `array_multisort()` and then remove them from array:

```
// INITIALIZE SORT ARRAYS
$mealarr = array();
$dayarr = array();

// APPEND TO MAIN AND SORT ARRAYS, NEW MEALNUMEBR AND DAYNUMBER ELEMENTS
for($i=0; $i<sizeof($breakfast); $i++){
    foreach ($breakfast[$i] as $key => $value) {               
         switch ($value) {                
             case "breakfast":   $breakfast[$i]['mealnumber'] = 1; $mealarr[] = 1; break;
             case "lunch":       $breakfast[$i]['mealnumber'] = 2; $mealarr[] = 2; break;
             case "dinner":      $breakfast[$i]['mealnumber'] = 3; $mealarr[] = 3; break;            

             case "monday":      $breakfast[$i]['daynumber'] = 1; $dayarr[] = 1; break;
             case "tuesday":     $breakfast[$i]['daynumber'] = 2; $dayarr[] = 2; break;
             case "wednesday":   $breakfast[$i]['daynumber'] = 3; $dayarr[] = 3; break;                
             case "thursday":    $breakfast[$i]['daynumber'] = 4; $dayarr[] = 4; break;
             case "friday":      $breakfast[$i]['daynumber'] = 5; $dayarr[] = 5; break;
             case "saturday":    $breakfast[$i]['daynumber'] = 6; $dayarr[] = 6; break;
             case "sunday":      $breakfast[$i]['daynumber'] = 7; $dayarr[] = 7; break;   
         }        
    }    
}
// SORT MAIN ARRAY
array_multisort($dayarr, SORT_ASC, $mealarr, SORT_ASC, $data); 

// REMOVE MEALNUMBER AND DAYNUMBER ELEMENTS
for($i=0; $i<sizeof($data); $i++){
    foreach ($data[$i] as $key => $value) {
        if ($key=='mealnumber' or $key=='daynumber') {
            unset($data[$i][$key]);
        }
    }
}
```